# "protocol error" when running ASP.NET Core on Cloud Run

Tags: asp.net-core, google-cloud-run, kestrel-http-server

My ASP.NET Core web app running in a container on Cloud Run gives this error when visited in the browser.

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: protocol error
```

I would like to use HTTP/2 if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when Cloud Run is configured to use HTTP/2 (`ports[n].name: h2c`) but Kestrel is configured for HTTP/1 or HTTP/1 and 2.

You need to force HTTP/2 only on Kestrel. One way to do this is with:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((options) =>
{
    options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(o => o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
});
```

For cases where Kestrel is configured for versions 1 and 2, I would guess the failure to negotiate has something to do with the connection being insecure since TLS is terminated at the Cloud Run infra.

Use this to check.

```
curl https://gemini-www-run-j2bjkfbw-ue.a.run.app/ --http2
```

Check CanIUse for browser compatibility with HTTP/2, if running a website.

Comment: Except that the Cloud Run application must only provide HTTP over the configured port (default is 8080). The communication between the Cloud Run frontend/proxy (GFE) and the application only supports HTTP. The frontend handles HTTPS/HTTP2 with the client and proxies to HTTP.

Comment: It supports http/2 end to end but that final leg is in the clear. My web server has forced http/2 and it works.